# Writing multiple columns from different files into one data frame in R

Tags: r, csv

I have the following files in the folder
***clust_rot_10_.csv,clust_rot_11_.csv,clust_rot_12_.csv,clust_rot_3_.csv,clust_rot_4_.csv,clust_rot_5_.csv,clust_rot_6_.csv,clust_rot_7_.csv,clust_rot_8_.csv,clust_rot_9_.csv,driver_rot_10_.csv,driver_rot_11_.csv,driver_rot_12_.csv,driver_rot_3_.csv,driver_rot_4_.csv,driver_rot_5_.csv,driver_rot_6_.csv,driver_rot_7_.csv,driver_rot_8_.csv,driver_rot_9_.csv***

In the files that start with *clust_rot_*, there are two columns X and Y. I need to retrieve the data from the Y column from all the files that start with *clust_rot_* using an R program. Please help with this

Comment: "Help" implies that you have already started the task and need assistance.  What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Can you please clarify a) in what way you want to merge the files into a data.frame (as different columns? all in the same two columns?) b) what the primary key is for merging two files into different columns (line number?).

Comment: I want them in the same file as different columns. The number of rows is the same in all the files. There's no primary key, I just want them side by side.

I need to automate this using a 'for' loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code -

```
#Get vector of filenames that has 'clust_rot_' in it. 
filenames <- list.files(pattern = 'clust_rot_', full.names = TRUE)
#From each file read the file and extract Y column from  it.
result <- as.data.frame(lapply(filenames, function(x) read.csv(x)$Y))
#Rename the columns with the name of the file
names(result) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(filenames))
#Write it as new csv
write.csv(result, 'result.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your input. However, the result file turns out to be empty. The second line of code did not read anything. The variable "result" has 0 observations.

Comment: 1. Does `filenames` have all the correct names of the file that you want to read? What does it contain? 2. Where are your csv files located? Is it in your working directory? check `getwd()`. If the files are not in working directory you need to give path of the csv files in `list.files`. `filenames <- list.files(path = '/location/of/csv/files', pattern = 'clust_rot_', full.names = TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry, Ronak. My bad the variable name was wrong. It is not Y, it is x. Thanks a lot for your help. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

The solution goes as follows:

1. Load the first file with `read.table` and store it in a data.frame *x*
2. In a loop over all remaining files, read each file into a temporary data.frame (e.g. *newdata*) and append it to the previously lodaed data with `cbind(x, newdata)`

Example with the builtin dataset *iris*:

```
x <- iris[,1:2]
newdata <- iris[,3:4]
x <- cbind(x, newdata)
```

Comment: firstly, thanks for your quick response. 
I understood the first part of your answer. However, I am not clear on the second part. 

It would be great if you could elaborate a bit or share the code, if possible.

Comment: I have added an example for the use of cbind.